# install redis on aws micro instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cli

I need to install redis in amazon cloud. I need it as a part of my npm module kue (deployment). Can anyone link me step by step tutorial or explain how to do it, considering the fact that I'm not good to bad with linux and administration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rather than spin up an EC2 instance and install/manage redis there, you could create an [Elasticache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) instance running redis and let AWS manage it all for you.

If you really do want to run your own redis server then you'll want to [launch an EC2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/LaunchingAndUsingInstances.html) and then [manually install redis](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart) onto it. The AWS and redis documentation that I've linked to both provide step by step instructions.

Comment: I tried the hard way. Will create Elasticache when I'm completely finished. For now I had an AWS AMI instance up and running. I have redis server installed. I managed to ping it on 127.0.0.1:6379. Now how can I use it from another aws instance. Again sorry for stupid questions but I've never done any administration before. I presume I have to make a rule for my aws security group for 6379 port and than I need to do a port forwarding while logged on aws instance, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You will need to add a rule to the security group to allow port 6379 through.  You don't need to set up any prot forwarding of any sort.

Comment: All is up and running. I chose a separate EC2 instance with manual redis installation. Now I'm returning to Elasticache approach. There is one thing I'm uncertain: As I needed redis for my npm kue module, does it share the sami interface?

Comment: Be warned: TLDR; Elasticache requires more time and $$. I took the advice of this answer and got sucked into the blackhole that is Elasticache.  I didn't get it working, wasted many hours all because AWS won't resolve it's node cluster DNS correctly. However you could pay for a $50/month contract to get basic support for them to resolve it... or you could just install on your EC2 instance.

Comment: I agree with you @MattJensen. Install Redis manually on EC2 is no biggie just follow below guide. For a Node.js app I'm making I think going with Amazon Elasticache only adds unnecessary complexity. Would much rather just have Redis running on localhost. https://gist.github.com/FUT/7db4608e4b8ee8423f31

Comment: @ChrisRch thanks, I think the real downside worth mentioning is that when you install on EC2 the best practices are 100% on you.  Most of the Redis install guides I've seen out there are the "quick and dirty" approach.  Take with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 104):

If you enable the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository that's present on Amazon Linux, you can install with yum.

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum install redis
# Start redis server
sudo redis-server /etc/redis.conf
```

Comment: Once you've run these commands, you can simply `sudo redis-server /etc/redis.conf` to start the server and run `redis-cli ping` to verify the redis server is running and accepting connections.

Comment: this deserves a separate question: "how to install redis on AMI linux"

Comment: For me `sudo redis-server` is enough

Comment: how to start on init??

Comment: Amazon CentOS: `sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb
sudo yum install redis

Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
No package redis available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: To start use `sudo systemctl start redis` and `sudo systemctl enable redis` to start on init

Answer (score 11):

On an Amazon Linux you can use [the Extras Library on EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-install-extras-library-software/):

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install redis6
```

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me on my "Amazon Linux 2" OS (based on RHEL/CENTOS 7)

```
wget -O /tmp/epel.rpm –nv https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y /tmp/epel.rpm
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install redis -y
```

After installation completes, start `redis-server` by typing this command

```
redis-server
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Works perfectly on Amazon Linux 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install redis on Amazon Linux. Here's the command.

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install redis6
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here seemed to work for me. Here's what did:

`sudo yum install redis6`

**Platform, date, and failed commands:**

[image: platform - date - failed command]

[image: more failed commands]

**Command that worked:**

[image: working command]

Answer (score 0):

I see answers here referencing ElastiCache. Note AWS recommends to use ElastiCache within the AWS backbone and not as a service that is intended to be connected to over the internet, such as your local dev station. That’s something to consider before embracing ElastiCache. In fact, in the ElastiCache [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/accessing-elasticache.html) under "Accessing ElastiCache resources from outside AWS”, it prompts you to install a NAT Instance. Not NAT Gateway, but a NAT Instance. Think about that. Clients must connect to an Elastic IP (associated with the EC2 Instance running as a NAT Instance on a public subnet of a custom vpc) and a cache port. Port forwarding on the NAT instance forwards traffic to the appropriate cache cluster node. Not only do you need to have a Security Group open with TCP protocol on 6379-6380, but you also have to configure iptables and verify that iptables opens the specified port (e.g. sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT && service iptables save).

If you truly need to access this cluster outside of aws, then as the OP asked for, use ec2. Installing redis-server on Amazon Linux 2023 is straightforward:

```
sudo dnf search redis
sudo dnf install -y redis6.x86_64
sudo systemctl start redis6
sudo systemctl enable redis6
sudo systemctl is-enabled redis6
redis6-server —version
redis6-cli ping
```

At this point, redis server is running through systemd. But it is probably listening on the loopback and not on all network interfaces:

```
ss -nlput
tcp                LISTEN              0                   511                                                    127.0.0.1:6379                                  0.0.0.0:*                                      
tcp                LISTEN              0                   128                                                         [::]:22                                       [::]:*                                      
tcp                LISTEN              0                   511                                                        [::1]:6379                                     [::]:*
```

Edit the configuration file:

```
sudo vi /etc/redis6/redis6.conf
```

Comment out the bind instruction:

```
# IF YOU ARE SURE YOU WANT YOUR INSTANCE TO LISTEN TO ALL THE INTERFACES
# JUST COMMENT OUT THE FOLLOWING LINE.
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#bind 127.0.0.1 -::1
```

Then reload redis server with systemctl:

```
sudo systemctl restart redis6
```

Now ss will show it as listening on all network interfaces:

```
ss -nlput
tcp            LISTEN          0               511                                              0.0.0.0:6379                          0.0.0.0:*              users:(("redis6-server",pid=28345,fd=6))            
tcp            LISTEN          0               128                                              0.0.0.0:22                            0.0.0.0:*              users:(("sshd",pid=2366,fd=3))                      
tcp            LISTEN          0               511                                                 [::]:6379                             [::]:*              users:(("redis6-server",pid=28345,fd=7))            
tcp            LISTEN          0               128                                                 [::]:22                               [::]:*              users:(("sshd",pid=2366,fd=4))
```

Now edit the inbound rules of the Security Group associated with the ENI of the EC2 Instance that is running redis-server. Add a Custom TCP Rule with Port range 6379 and source set to 0.0.0.0/0 or even better the IP range you expect to be accessing redis through. Then access from your local workstation using the public ip of the ec2 instance and the port redis is listening on:

```
redis-cli -h [ec2-instance-public-ip] -p 6379
```

I tested from my MacBook Pro and it worked. Note AWS recommends to create an Elastic IP, as it is an unchanging IP address. Go to the EC2 Console, click on "Elastic IPs", and click "Allocate Elastic IP address”. Then click on the newly created Elastic IP address, select Actions and click on Associate Elastic IP address. Select the Instance you have redis server running in. Choose a private IP address with which to associate the Elastic IP address.

```
redis-cli -h [elastic-ip-associated-with-instance] -p 6379
```