# How to install/manage Redis Cluster on AWS EC2, not ElastiCache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, aws-cli, redis-cli

Due to some historical/incident reasons, my company cannot use AWS ElastiCache, so can someone recommend a step-by-step tutorial on how to configure a Redis **Cluster** on AWS EC2?

This [install redis on aws micro instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690142/install-redis-on-aws-micro-instance) has already been very answered how a single Redis instance could be installed.

But in terms of installing a Redis **Cluster**, no further information is provided and I searched on the Internet, no clear tutorials/examples are found, e.g. which cluster management should be used? ZooKeeper, Mesos, etc?
And anything else should be paid attention be, when developing, configuring and deploying to production.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you looked at the RedisLabs offerings like Redis Cloud? https://redislabs.com/products/redis-cloud/ I would look at that before trying to build my own solution.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your suggestions, but I need to stick with AWS for company compliance, not another offering. Thanks.

Comment: How about the Redis offering on AWS - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B016WJQY84?ref=cns_srchrow

Comment: You can run the RedisLabs Redis Cloud product in your AWS account.

Comment: @stdunbar, thanks for the suggestion. But it adds additional cost, for C4.xlarge instance type, it's $0.199/hour. This is too expensive for us. We'd prefer to just configure it ourselves.

Comment: I can put it on a t2.medium ($0.047 hourly) if I use a VPC or an m3.medium ($0.067 hourly) if i don't.  I'm not seeing a requirement of a c4.xlarge though that is an option.

Comment: Sure, it's definitely not required. But we need to use c4.xlarge as our instance type due to our data size.

Comment: @FisherCoder if you use Redis Labs' Redis Cloud offering on AWS, then you tell them what data size you have, what features you need and they manage the whole thing for you.

The other option is to use what stdunbar mentions below and deploy what used to be called RLEC, but is recently renamed to Redis Enterprise Pack on EC2 instances either through the marketplace or with your own AMI.

Answer (score 3):

The Redis Labs Enterprise Cluster (RLEC) is available via the [AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B016WJQY84?ref=cns_srchrow).  In addition, there is a [fully managed version](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01LZM49M6?qid=1486582903733&sr=0-2&ref_=srh_res_product_title) available too though, by definition, that isn't self install.

Comment: Seems like the mentioned items are no longer available.  This one maybe a successor: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-mwscixe4ujhkq?sr=0-2&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa